# There are two arrows spinning next to my Wifi

Tags: itunes, music

There are two arrows moving in a circle next to the Wifi bars. I am confused. I was wondering if this means something is downloading because I just trying to sync music from my ITunes on PC, to my IPad, but everytime I click on a song, it says "Item Not Available." Do the arrows mean something is downloading? If not, what are they an indicator for?

Answer (score 2):

This is the iTunes sync indicator, which indicates that the device is syncing with iTunes over USB or Wi-Fi.